# Show all data table value into text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I want to show my data table column value into text box but its showing only one row value my Query returns only two columns and i want to show both column in  text box similar to datatable

My data table has two column col1 and col2 i want to show this column value into text box
 I want to show my text vale similar to this 
    col1             col2
    @ID          int,
    @additional  varchar(max),
    @Mail_ID     varchar(max)

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                textBox5.Text = String.Empty;
                string strSQLConn = "Server =" + textBox1.Text + "; Initial Catalog =" + textBox2.Text + "; User ID =" + textBox3.Text + "; Password = " + textBox4.Text + ";";
                SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(strSQLConn);
                SQLConn.Open();
                foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
                    SqlCommand SQLcmd2 = new SqlCommand("WITH cte AS (SELECT '@' + COLUMN_NAME AS c1, CASE DATA_TYPE WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN 'varchar(max)' WHEN 'NVARCHAR' THEN 'nvarchar(max)' WHEN 'INT' THEN 'int' WHEN 'DATETIME' THEN 'Datetime()' WHEN 'Float' THEN 'float' END AS c2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE) AS rn, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + row["Table_Name"] + "') SELECT c1 As col1, c2 +CASE WHEN rn<cnt THEN ',' ELSE '' END AS col2 FROM cte;", SQLConn);

                    SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataAdapter Da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd2);
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                    Da2.Fill(dt2);                 
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt2.Columns)
                        {
                            result.Append(dr[dc].ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    textBox5.Text = result.ToString();
                    textBox5.Text += "Create Proc SP_Insert_"+ row["Table_Name"] + Environment.NewLine +"Declare"+ " ( " + dt2.Rows[0]["col1"].ToString()
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
textBox5.Text = result.ToString();
```

It replaces any previous value, from the previous rows.
Instead, do something like this:

```
if (textBox5.Text != string.empty) textBox5.Text += environment.NewLine;
textBox5.Text += result.ToString();
```

Also (just spotted this) you reset the result for every row. Move this line outside the loop:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: i use same sa you mention but still i am getting something like this  @IDint,@additionalvarchar(max),@Mail_IDvarchar(max)

Comment: Did you change the `=` to `+=` in the second line? Have you stepped through the code to check your query actually returns multiple rows?

Comment: if (textBox5.Text != string.Empty) textBox5.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                    textBox5.Text += result.ToString();

Comment: i changed = to +=

Comment: my query returns only two rows one is for column name and another one is for data type

Comment: my data table value as shown ID int,
additional varchar(max),
Mail_ID varchar(max)

Comment: I think I found the problem, move `StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();` outside the loop

Comment: its an instance of class how can i put inside loop please guide i think it should be outside

Comment: but i am not sure

Comment: inside loop how can we place StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

Comment: Move it to just above `foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)`

Comment: i did but no any change Robin i want my column data in new line so we need to change in loop i think instead of changing StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder()